# SQL - how to skip a row if it contains similar information when compared to the previous row?

Tags: sql-server-2008

my table looks like this:

```
ID#  Type    Color
1.   Clothes Red
2.   Clothes Orange
3.   Clothes OrangeYellow
4.   Clothes Green
5.   Clothes Red
```

Desired result:

```
ID#  Type    Color
1.   Clothes Red
2.   Clothes Orange
4.   Clothes Green
5.   Clothes Red
```

My SQL doesn't seem to support LAG function

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your query? And yes, [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) is available in SQL Server only starting from 2012 version.

Comment: I understand, which is why i can't use the LAG function to walk through the rows,  I just have a simple query that says select * from mydatabase where type ='clothes' order by ID#

Answer (score 0):

You could use this subquery approach using `LIKE` with `% previous-color %`:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.Color
FROM dbo.Colors c
WHERE NOT EXISTS  -- check if previous row has a similar color
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Colors cPrev
    WHERE cPrev.ID = (SELECT MAX(cMax.ID) 
                      FROM dbo.Colors cMax
                      WHERE cMax.ID < c.ID)  -- maximum id lower than this
    AND c.Color LIKE '%' + cPrev.Color + '%'
)
```